# Data Loader Download Not Working on Mac

Tags: data-loader, error, data

I have exported a list of accounts with account owners and other info from Production and have reassigned accounts to new owners in excel.  I would like to now use the Data Loader to push these changes into the sandbox and eventually move the changes to production.  After downloading Data Loader for Mac I got an error when I try to open it saying "Data Loader is Damaged and Can't Be Opened.  You should move it to the Trash"  How do I fix this? Or is there another tool I can use to reassign accounts based on the excel file?

Comment: Please Help ASAP boss is really on me

Comment: Do a google search for Lexiloader. It still works

Comment: You can use salesforce built-in data loader functionality.

Answer (score 3):

It is a mac thing. Go to System preferences, Security and Privacy, click the padlock, type in password, check option Allow apps downloaded from: Anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://dataloader.io/ . All you need to do is log in with your org credentials...It's pretty fast and more efficient than the Apex Data Loader. As you are saying it's very important to get this job done, this is would be the best way.

Comment: I love dataloader.io but I can't get Upsert to work with external ID of Email.

Comment: Use workbench. Log in to workbench.developerforce.com/login.php . Under Data section, you will have the option to insert/upsert/update and delete records. Direct link for upsert: https://workbench.developerforce.com/upsert.php

Comment: Got dataloader.io to work. https://dataloader.io/using-import-lookups helped a lot.

Comment: Good to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on data loader and then view package contents, browse to the MacOS folder and run the java executable there directly. Seemed to do it for me

Answer (score 0):

Actually, why don't you use **Mass Transfer Records** feature? That's the efficient way of transferring records to a different owner. You can transfer 250 records at a time. Unless you have more than 2000 records to transfer, **Mass Transfer Records** is the best way to do. In the Set Up search box, search for Mass Transfer Records....it is pretty straight forward and nothing confusing even for a first timer....

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce Mac dataloader now works, there was an issue with the version online which has been fixed now. If you download the current version it will run ok.

Comment: Not for me! The application “Data Loader” can’t be opened. http://i.stack.imgur.com/yz0nJ.png